# Is there focus and lost-focus event on black berry sdk?

Tags: blackberry

I am very new developer for black berry environment. Is there a focus and lost-focus event for the controls which are currently selected or deselected?

Please give me some like or example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are writing your own custom field, or want to catch the events of your `Screen` class(es), then you would override the virtual `Field.onFocus()` and `Field.onUnfocus()` methods.

If you want to catch focus events of other fields, then you have to implement the `FocusChangeListener` interface and then call the `Field.setFocusChangeListener()` method of those fields.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are `Field.onFocus(int direction)` and `Field.onUnfocus()`. Check the API for details.